# quicker way to set variable on page, instead of having in each if statement

Tags: php, html

I have a fairly straight-forward validation system on my registration page within my website. It all works fine, however, it seems unnecessarily messy; with always checking if a variable (`$regOpen`) is true, and then setting a variable (`$errors`) to true each time there is an error.

This is the very ***simplified*** script and relative **HTML**:

```
<?php 
    $regOpen = false;
    $errors = false;

    if(Input::is("register")){ // if a user has clicked register
        $regOpen = true;
    }

    if($regOpen){ // checking if input is set first time
        if(Input::empty("email")){
            echo '<span>Your email address must not be left blank.</span>';
            $errors = true; // setting to true for the first time
        }
        if($email->exists()){
            echo '<span>A user with that email already exists.</span>';
            $errors = true; // 2nd
        }
        if(!filter_var(Input::get("email"), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            echo '<span>That is not a valid email type.</span>';
            $errors = true; // 3rd
        }
    }
?>
<input type="text" name="email">

<?php 
    if($regOpen){ // 2nd
        if(Input::empty("password")){
            echo '<span>Your password must not be left blank.</span>';
            $errors = true; // 4th
        }
        if(strlen(Input::get("password")) < 4){
            echo '<span>Your password must be a minimum of 4 characters.</span>';
            $errors = true; // 5th
        }
    }
?>
<input type="password" name="password">

<?php 
    if($errors){ // if there are errors
        echo '<span>Registration failed.</span>';
    } else {
        // register user 
        echo '<span>Registration successful.</span>;
    }
?>
```

In reality, I actually have about several fields I need to check (each with their own list of errors to check), so as you can imagine; checking and setting all these variables seems a bit tedious and unnecessary.

What I want to know is, if there is a way to only have to set the `$errors` variable to true, once. Not only that, if there is a way to reduce the way I check if `$regOpen` is `true` (instead of checking each time I need to check for errors).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$errors` as an array for errors instead of being just an indicator. Then you could check if `$errors` array is not empty, then it contains errors.

Here's a clearer version of your code:

```
<?php 

function print_errors($errors) {
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo '<span>' . $error . '</span>';
    }
}

$regOpen = Input::is("register");
$errors = [];

if($regOpen){ // checking if input is set first time
    if(Input::empty("email")){
        $errors['email'][] = "Your email address must not be left blank.";
    }
    if($email->exists()){
        $errors['email'][] = "A user with that email already exists.";
    }
    if(!filter_var(Input::get("email"), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $errors['email'][] = "That is not a valid email type.";
    }
    if(Input::empty("password")){
        $errors['password'][] = "Your password must not be left blank.";
    }
    if(strlen(Input::get("password")) < 4){
        $errors['password'][] = "Your password must be a minimum of 4 characters.";
    }
}
?>

<?php isset($errors['email']) ? print_errors($errors['email']) : null; ?>
<input type="text" name="email">

<?php isset($errors['password']) ? print_errors($errors['password']) : null; ?>
<input type="password" name="password">

<?php 
if(count($errors) > 0){ // if there are errors
    echo '<span>Registration failed.</span>';
} else {
    // register user 
    echo '<span>Registration successful.</span>';
}
?>
```

You may now get the idea.

Comment: Hmm, this is actually a very smart approach!

Comment: Thanks! Hope it helps.

Comment: I've noticed that it will pop up with errors before the inputs stating that there is an undefined index, such as `Undefined index: email`

Comment: I updated the answer. It was just a PHP Notice that can be turned off without affecting the actual result. Anyway, I added a check before calling print_errors which will fix this notice.

Comment: For some reason, I'm getting the error, `Headers already sent`.

Comment: This error can't be caused by the posted code, do you use `header()` or `session_start()` anywhere in your code? Anyway, this is not related to your original question so you should search on stackoverflow because this is a very common error or ask a separate question with more details and full code if you can't find anything that matches your case.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, many of the checking are not necessary at PHP level, you can use the [HTML 5 form validation](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/) for many cases. Secondly, for a few case that HTML5 form validation can't handle, you don't need to purposely set `$errors=true`, you could do something like `$error=$email->exists();`.

Comment: Not sure if you're aware, but anything on the client-side can be altered and bypassed.

Comment: I'm only here to help. If you are aware of html validation and don't want to use it, please say so in your post.